# GeometryReader not generating correct screen height?

Tags: watchkit, swiftui

```
public var body: some View  
{  
  ZStack{  

     GeometryReader { geometry in  
          RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 25, style: .continuous)  
            .frame(width: geometry.size.width*1.00, height: geometry.size.height*1.00)  
            .zIndex(0)  
      }  
  }  
}
```

I'm using GeometryReader to draw a rounded rectangle to fill up the entire watch screen, this looks fine on a 38mm watch simulator, but as I increase the watch size to 40, 42, 44mm I noticed that the height is not filling up the whole screen. I have to adjust my multiple to say 1.1 for example to fill up more of the screen.

Can someone tell me if I am using GeometryReader incorrectly?

Answer (score 1):

Unless you really need the full functionality of the geometry reader, to actually measure the size of the object of the screen, then I think you could achieve the effect you want by setting the frame's `maxWidth` and `maxHeight` to `.infinity` and by ignoring the safe area on the bottom.

```
var body: some View {
    ZStack {
        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 25, style: .continuous)
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
            .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.bottom)
        }
}
```

Note that when you use a `ZStack` the order of the items in it determine the order on the screen. The first item in the stack will be at the bottom, and then each item will be layered on top.

Comment: Using .infinity seems to have inconsistent results, some times the view is loading and stretching all the way to the bottom, sometimes it's going around 80-90% to the bottom like the way my code snippet is.

Comment: I’ve used this on all the simulators with the expected result. Are you using the `.edgesIgnoringSafeArea` modifier?